# How do I join these 3 tables together?

Tags: sql, join

Having a hard time wrapping my head around this. Here are the 3 tables.
[image]

I need to be able to show the employee names and their current and previous jobs.

I tried this, but I am not getting the right results:

```
SELECT
  HR.E.FIRST_NAME,
  HR.E.LAST_NAME,
  HR.J.JOB_ID,
  HR.JH.JOB_ID OLD_JOB_ID

FROM
  HR.JOBS J
LEFT JOIN HR.EMPLOYEES E ON E.JOB_ID = J.JOB_ID
LEFT JOIN HR.JOB_HISTORY JH ON JH.JOB_ID = J.JOB_ID
```

I get:

```
First Name | Last Name | JOB ID | OLD JOB ID |
John       | Smith     | Admin  | (null)     |
```

Comment: What's stored in the JOB_HISTORY table? All jobs, including current? Or just past jobs?

Answer (score 1):

If you join `EMPLOYEES` and `JOBS` directly, you only get the current job for every employee. Join `EMPLOYEES` with `JOB_HISTORY` and you get every job every employee ever had and join the result with `JOBS` to get the respective job title for every job history entry:

```
SELECT
  HR.E.FIRST_NAME,
  HR.E.LAST_NAME,
  HR.J.JOB_TITLE,
  HR.JH.JOB_ID

FROM
  HR.EMPLOYEES E
LEFT JOIN HR.JOB_HISTORY JH ON JH.EMPLOYEE_ID = E.EMPLOYEE_ID
LEFT JOIN HR.JOBS J ON J.JOB_ID = JH.JOB_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should start with `UNION ALL` the `EMPLOYEES` and `JOB_HISTORY` tables, to get them all together. Then `JOIN` that result with `jobs` table:

```
select *
from jobs j
join (select * from EMPLOYEES
      UNION ALL
      select * from JOB_HISTORY) as all_emp
  ON all_emp.JOB_ID = j.JOB_ID
```

(I'd rather have only one table for all employments, both current and past.)